# Trusted connection to sql server via user identity in MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp-classic

I am using ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider and want to connect to Sql Server with Integrated  connection using user identity.

"Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=maindb;Integrated Security=True"

How to do it if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

By default

```
Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=maindb;Integrated Security=True
```

will use ApplicationPoolIdentity in MVC.

You can grab Username/Password after using ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider to connect to database with

```
Integrated Security=False
```

Comment: Yes, it is a way to solve my problem. But i think that it isn't a good idea for security reasons

Answer (score 0):

create Windows user who will be authorized for running app pool in IIS and connect to SQL server on the level you need, not the SA level. Make sure that user have SQL server authorization just in case.

Make sure that your site is using that user to run in Web Server security settings.

Create app pool and assign user to run it and to your site.

That should take care of your question.